# How do i set up an windows application vb 2008 and mysql database in a server and access it with a client?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, network-programming, client-server

How do i set up  an windows application vb 2008 and mysql database in a server and access it with a client? 
i want to put my application and database in a server and access it with clients in a network.
i tried sharing the application ,it works fine but it can't locate the database ,the application still runs but without a database...

i installed xampplite for the server computer and run it... then accessed the application with a client computer..
when loading the application pops up an error with the database but you can choose to continue but you will run the application without a dabase?
how do i access the database in the server with client computers?

Comment: If you are using MySQL as database, you have to allow access from network. Check server firewall settings

Comment: @GiorgiTBS yes i am using mysql database... we tried connecting to other computers... it works just fine but when i tried to access it on the server this error comes up 'host "PC NAME" is not allowed to connect to this mysql server'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if you have port 3306 opened on firewall
2. Uncomment in my.ini this line: bind-address=SERVER-IP (replace Server-IP with your server IP address